# Надпись «черновик сохранён» налезает на флажок «общий»

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн, правки, редактор

Как минимум, эти два элемента должны быть на одной линии. Как максимум, надпись нужно переместить, так как галочка «общий» съезжает влево при появлении надписи-уведомления.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тоже замечал этот косяк, даже скриншоты подготовил :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Спасибо за отзыв! [Дефект исправили](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297176), в ближайшей сборке будет доступен на сайте.