# Не скрывается шапка при раскрытом окне сниппета

Tags: дефект

Проблема в слишком высоком уровне слоя шапки:

> [image: пример сниппета]

**Воспроизведение:**
Раскрыть любой сниппет на весь экран и увидеть что шапка **не** скрыта.

**Рекомендации:**
У `.so-header` стоит `z-index` равный 1050, тогда как у `iframe`, который отображает сниппет, `z-index` которого 1030.
Необходимо чтобы слой шапки был **меньше** слоя раскрытого сниппета.

Comment: Мета — и есть багтрекер. ) Пожалуйста, не нужно копить N багов в одном вопросе. Их так отслеживать трудно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, мета - это куча всего в одном: баги, предложения, обсуждения, новости, анонсы и чёрт в ступе. Но моё дело предложить :)

Comment: Ну да, много всего в одном месте, сложно заточить его под конкретные задачи.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, так почему не поставить подобие Jira на отдельный домен?

Comment: Наверное, дело в сложности поддержки. Нужно будет админить Java-стек, которого в SO вроде бы нет. Авторизацию прокидывать из этого сайта. А ещё туда никто не будет ходить. ))

Comment: @NickVolynkin, Согласился бы для большинства сайтов, но тут каждый первый завсегдатай - разработчик, поэтому идея использовать мысли/предложения по разработке от посетителей тут как нельзя актуальна. Могли бы хотя бы попробовать.

Comment: Вот, кстати, и ещё одна причина. Тут — это на SO? Есть ещё сайты для поваров, велосипедистов и последователей разных религий. Поддерживать сервис ради всего нескольких сайтов наверняка ещё более затратно. Ну и стоимость лицензии велика.

Comment: В общем, не взлетит. Лучше расскажите, чего вам не хватает, чтобы здесь было удобно баги репортить?

Comment: Того, чего нет без нормальной системы отслеживания багов: ранжирование по приоритету/типу, время отклика на багу, назначение ответственных, да и, собственно, главного - необязательность к исполнению. Тут, на мете, можно запросить фикс, но далеко не факт что его кто-то примет и пофиксит.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59962/discussion-between-nick-volynkin-and-aid).

Comment: По первому пункту уже заведена [бага](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5368/176217). Так что вопрос можно уменьшить и переименовать.

Comment: @alexolut, Вы довольны?

Comment: @Aid не совсем. Время суток не доброе :)

Comment: @alexolut, читайте в другое время :)

Comment: @alexolut, не утерпели? :)

Comment: Меньше хлама, больше смысла! Пора привыкать.

Comment: @alexolut, да весь этот спор - хлам, модер придёт и атата нам сделает. Приветствие же - не хлам.

Comment: Однократно может и не хлам. Но Вы не здороваетесь несколько раз на дню с одним и тем же человеком!

Comment: @alexolut, вообще-то здороваюсь, но это мой глюк. Сообщение - отдельный сеанс связи с читателем, который должен иметь приветственный пакет для handshake и финальный.