# Хэдер показывается поверх оверлея

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн

Хэдер показывается поверх оверлея диалога загрузки картинки, причём довольно странно сохраняет интерактивность - при установке фокуса в поле поиска диалог исчезает, а оверлей - нет.

Header shows over load picture dialog's overlay. It also is strangely interactive: if you put focus to search field, the dialog will disappear, but overlay won't.

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Большое спасибо за ваш отзыв! Обнаруженная вами проблема задевала все сайты сети, на которых был доступен редактор изображений и активны фрагменты кода. Проблема заключалась в том, что неверное значение z-индекса назначалось через JavaScript–код. Проблема устранена, исправление будет доступно в следующей сборке.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5385/207618