# Нет кнопки "Закрыть" при полноэкранном сниппете

Tags: дефект

Дефект связан с криво пофикшенной [проблемой](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5385/207618).
`iframe` теперь выше всех (`z-index: 9000`), а вот кнопка закрытия `.popin` осталась снизу (`z-index: 1051`).

**Воспроизведение:**
Зайти на страницу с любым сниппетом, нажать "Выполнить код", появится кнопка "На всю страницу", что приведёт к раскрытию сниппета и наблюдению бага.

```html
<strong>Ворнинг</strong>:<br />
Вход в полноэкранный режим до исправления бага чреват тем, что без изменения вручную `z-index`, Вам придётся только перезагрузить страниц, ибо выхода не будет.
```

Comment: А чего сниппет в вопрос не добавил?

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну а почему бы и нет?

Comment: Скажите, любезный, а *ворнинг* можно было разместить **до** сниппета?

Comment: @Arhad, не думаю что кто-то запустит сниппет до полного прочтения.

Comment: Потому и написал «любезный», что как минимум я попался в эту ловушку.

Comment: @Arhad, будет уроком - сначала читай, а потом действуй.

Comment: @Aid можно было ворнинг поместить в текст сниппета)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, по просьбам трудящихся...

Comment: @Aid говоря на школолошном: "Азазазаза ЛОЛ" ))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Моя твоя не понимать.